# Xamarin Forms - Traçar rota GPS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xaml, gps, cross-platform

Caros, boa noite!

Alguém tem algum exemplo de como utilizar GPS no Xamarin? Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto (PCL), que iria traçar a rota entre dois pontos, mas estou com algumas duvidas ainda.

Eu consigo traçar a rota apenas com o endereço? Ou somente com latitude e longitude?

Eu procurei por exemplos de utilização do GPS no Xamarin, mas não consegui achar nada, apenas exemplos utilizando Maps, que somente mostra no mapa a localização, e não traça nenhuma rota.

Att.
Felipe

Comment: É uma `PCL` para utilização com `xamarin-forms` ou é um projeto `xamarin-forms`? Pra mim ficou confuso qual cenário exatamente será utilizado.

Answer (score -1):

Oi, creio que para cada plataforma você usará um mapa específico como bing maps, google maps ou outros.
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/GooglePlayServices/
Vê se isso te ajuda.